# Cups printing and setting CPI LPI

Tags: cups

We are currently moving over from Sco to Redhat and we have been told to install CUPS for printing. 
We do only text printing invoices reports etc. 
How do I change the settings on my printers CPI LPI etc?

Answer (score 1):

These days, text only printing is a very long way from the mainstream.

If you are using the textonly.ppd file, then only ascii text is ever sent to the printer - you need to tweak the .ppd file to set the page size, but CPI/LPI cannot be sent from the driver - you need to either embed the relevant codes in your output stream (assuming cups doesn't strip them out) or set them using the dip swiches on your printer.

It might be simpler to use the BSD printing system (assuming RH still support it).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CUPS documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/options.html).  If you're submitting ASCII text jobs via `LPR` you can set `-o cpi=10` for characters/inch and `-o lpi=6` for lines/inch.